# What does it take to host my own mongodb server for dev works?

Tags: mongodb

I currently have mLab account and I have been using it for quite sometime. But I don't want to pay that much monthly for dev works. I am aware I can set up mongodb on my own server. But can someone please give me what it takes for me to do so? Thanks in advance

Comment: I can suggest you use digital ocean, they have pretty good 1GB RAM 30 GB SSD droplets for only 5 $ monthly. By using my referral code you will get  free 10$ credit https://m.do.co/c/f157250fd186 and then I can get some referral bonuses

Comment: If you don't wants to spend money install mongo on your own computer.